# Review: peer-to-peer encrypted communication

Tags: encryption, certificates

I'd like to ask you to review security of the following communication scheme:

- network is strictly P2P, based on DHT (peer discovery)
- root user can create a virtual private network (network private and public keys)
- peers belong to private networks
- if peer wants to join the virtual network, they need to pass their public key to the root, to sign it with the network key
- peers uses DHT to find other nodes (peers) and establishes direct communication using UTP. The communication is encrypted with a common secret key, decided by both sides (Diffie Hellman).
- both sides can verify if the other peer's public key is signed with the network certificate.

Questions:

- how can I implement certificate revocation? I considered passing announcements between peers
- is there a way to detect that an attacker stole a private key? I thought about a fingerprint based on MAC/computer name/etc.

The best option for me would be eliminating the root user at all and let the group decide if invite/revoke another peer or not.

I know that the signal implements private groups, but in this model you don't have all peers available for 100% time, so you can't decide together on the new key once somebody joins/leave - hence certificates.

Thank you in advance for any ideas, complaints, hints.